# Getting NoSuchMethodError Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider when upgrading to spring boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I am getting  noclassdeffound error when i upgraded from spring boot 1.1 to spring boot 2. Hibernate validator jar:6.0.9. validation-api:2.0.1. Following is the stacktrace.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.Configuration.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.configureParameterNameProvider(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:314) [spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:290) [spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: ok, and what is the actual question?